# Samsung Tizen AVPlayer error when playing HLS stream

Tags: video-streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming, samsung-smart-tv, adaptive-bitrate

I started working on a new IPTV app and AVPlayer cannot open my HLS live streams in specific.
I tested the player with other HLS stream samples and they worked fine. also .mp4 videos from the same website url are working fine.
I have searched alot about the reason why these certain live streams are not working but I could't find a solution. I tested them on android and VLC and they work fine.

here is a stream example :

http://avatar-iptv.net:1795/azizmobi/w8xm9KzFNa/436

my code is

Code

```
webapis.avplay.setStreamingProperty("ADAPTIVE_INFO", "BITRATES=2000~100000|STARTBITRATE=LOWEST");
webapis.avplay.prepare();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check carefully the AVPlay [state changes](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay) in order to load the multimedia content correctly

You can also check the [reference AVPlay demo](https://github.com/Samsung/TizenTVApps/tree/master/TVDemoAvPlayer) provided by Samsung

Comment: I am already using this demo for stream and video testing.  the same problem happens. i have read the console log and found that an error happens after buffering state, but I cannot get any useful information about the error. I think the problem is in the stream not the player but I can't figure out what it is and how to solve it. maybe it has wrong settings, bitrates, transcoding or aac audio setting. I don't have a clue. the same stream is working in samsung legacy tv platform but not tizen.

Comment: Maybe it's not the best way to get it work but, have you tried the video tag? 2016 Tizen TVs and above versions supports adaptative streams on video tag

Comment: I have tried hls.js library which uses video tag. the same problem happened.

Comment: Got it, but you should not need to use third-party libraries to play HLS content (the video tag, the src and the application / vnd.apple.mpegurl type should be enough). Maybe you can find an HLS validator

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I tested your stream in a sample app, and it works.

Comment: No, I didn't. could you please send me a link to this sample app. Maybe there is something wrong with my sample apps structure.